# Factor level Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Tags: r, regression, selection

Hi I am trying to do best subset selection with nhanes2003-2004 dataset.

`load("/Users/nhanes2003-2004.Rda")
regfit.full=regsubsets(RIDAGEEX~.,data=nhanes2003_2004)`

And I keep getting this error message

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Here is a snapshot of the data, which can also be acessed through https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/ContinuousNhanes/Default.aspx?BeginYear=2003
[image]

How do I check the level of factor and avoid this error message? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to select only those columns having `unique` values more than `1` in a column.

```
# Columns having unique values more than one 
validcols <- sapply(nhanes2003_2004, 
    function(x)length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) > 1)

#Select only valid columns 
df <- nhanes2003_2004[,validcols]

#Perfomr analysis on df
```